# Multiple #define within #ifdef or #ifndef

Tags: c++

This is a simple question, but I have not ran across similar code before to know the answer. Basically, am I allowed to have more than two #define in an #ifdef or #ifndef statement? For a basic example:

```
    #ifdef __GNUC__
        #define HELLO(x) x
        #define WORLD(y) y
    #else
        #define __attribute__(x)
        #define expect(expression, value) (expression)
    #endif
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you are. This is perfectly valid.

You can have as many C statements or preprocessor directives within a preprocessor block as you want.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you may have as many preprocessor directives or just normal C++ statements between an `#ifdef` / `#ifndef` ... [`#else`] ... `#endif` block as you want.

This is a simple enough question that you probably should have tried it before asking though.

Comment: Though there's enough _unspecified behavior_, _undefined behavior_, and _implementation defined behavior_ in C that "just try it" is sometimes the exact wrong approach to suggest. :)

Comment: For C itself that's true - but for the preprocessor?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Variadic macros in C++ ?